# Passing variable value from function in a class in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I'm working with as3 and I don't understand how to pass from a value on a function to a global variable. I have this code (in a .as file):

```
package {

public class loadInfo {
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;

    private var teamA:String;

    public var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader( );

    public function loadInfo() {
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
        urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("data.txt" ));
    }

    public function handleComplete( event:Event ):void {
        this.teamA = urlLoader.data.teamA;
    }
    public function getTeamA():String{
        return teamA;
    }
  }

}
```

What I'm doing with this code is to load several variables which are in a .txt file.

and in the .fla file I have:

```
import loadInfo;

var dat:loadInfo = new loadInfo();
trace(dat.getTeamA());
```

but the result is "null".
So, I have no clue what to do. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't wait for the loader to complete. It takes time to load that txt file and if you call `getTeamA` immediately, the loader isn't finished. You should do something like this:

```
var dat:loadInfo = new loadInfo();
dat.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataLoaded);

function onDataLoaded(e:Event):void {
    trace (dat.getTeamA());
}
```

And within `loaderInfo`:

```
public function handleComplete( event:Event ):void {
    this.teamA = urlLoader.data.teamA;
    dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
}
```

Should work properly. Keep in mind that `loaderInfo` must extend EventDispatcher (`class loaderInfo extends EventDispatcher {`)..